# High CPU usage from the Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer Thread

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a application which uses Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer and IBM mq as the message broker, after running application for certain time, the cpu usage spiked with other threads with similar cpu usage. Below is one of the messageListenerContainer thread from thread dump with top command.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
29410 tomcat    20   0   10.4g   4.0g  20320 R 25.0 12.6 610:36.22 msgListenerCont
```

```
"msgListenerContainer" #265306 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=36635917.55ms elapsed=3263601.16s tid=0x00007f8804046800 nid=0x72e2 runnable  [0x00007f87abe79000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.set(java.base@11.0.7/ThreadLocal.java:487)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.set(java.base@11.0.7/ThreadLocal.java:222)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.locking.TraceableLock.incrementDepth(TraceableLock.java:99)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.locking.TraceableLock.lock(TraceableLock.java:90)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.locking.TraceableReentrantLock.lock(TraceableReentrantLock.java:73)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.util.HconnLock.lock(HconnLock.java:83)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.requestMutex(RemoteProxyQueue.java:367)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.requestMessagesReconnectable(RemoteProxyQueue.java:1046)
    - locked <0x00000007166f9d48> (a com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession$RequestMessagesMutex)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.requestMessages(RemoteProxyQueue.java:717)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.flushQueue(RemoteProxyQueue.java:1911)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteProxyQueue.proxyMQGET(RemoteProxyQueue.java:2783)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternalWithRecon(RemoteFAP.java:6103)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGetInternal(RemoteFAP.java:5992)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.JmqiTools.getMessage(JmqiTools.java:1371)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiGet(RemoteFAP.java:5957)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiGet(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:1341)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiGet(ESEJMQI.java:602)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.getMsg(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1795)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.receiveInternal(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:228)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.receive(WMQConsumerShadow.java:1461)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.receive(WMQMessageConsumer.java:674)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receiveInboundMessage(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:1051)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.receive(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:667)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQMessageConsumer.receive(MQMessageConsumer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:418)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:303)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:257)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1189)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1179)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1076)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.7/Thread.java:834)
```

From above thread stack trace it looks to me that thread is stuck doing something with ThreadLocalMap.set method, but other than that I can't find why it is using so much cpu.

Comment: I am using spring version 5.3.18, java 11 and ibm mq 9.2.0.1

Comment: Have you tried a SimpleMessageListenerContainer? These are much more efficient.

Comment: Did you try and change `spring.jms.listener.receiveTimeout` to a higher value (default is 1 second)? If you use the MQ JMS Spring Boot Start this would be done automatically, see [JMS Polling Listener Timer configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring#jms-polling-listener-timer-configuration).

Comment: @JoshMc, we have using DefaultMessageListenerContainer for all our spring, spring boot application and not issue in other applications, just one application and for a specific node this is happening, Thanks you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann, I have tried the receiveTimeout to 60000ms (60sec) but I have yet to try in Production environment, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @DanielSteinmann, Also this particular application is not spring boot application, it is spring application but deployed in tomcat, spring version 5.3.18, java 11, ibm mq client library 9.2.0.1. thanks

Comment: This could be just about anything (sorry, not very helpful).  In general, the problem that you run into with Spring JMS is that the message listener will receive one message, then close the session and connection and then reconnect to the message broker.  If you only receive one message every few minutes, this may be fine.  For any decent message rate, this is not acceptable.  As mentioned, the receive timeout default value of one second is also problematic.  I would recommend enabling the IBM MQ java logging.  This may help you determine what resource is being exhausted.

Comment: @DougGrove, thanks for the comment. I will try to change configuration and test it out again.

Comment: @pravinhada if this worked for you (it did for me), it would be great that you publish and accept a solution

Comment: For now I have added other DMLC property maxMessagesPerTask to scale down the number of concurrent thread created to concurrentConsumer thread after the specified time in secs. Testing is still going on and so far I don't see any issue adding this property